LibreOffice Writer Context Menus Out of Position
When using LibreOffice Writer, a right mouse click raises a context sensitive menu.  However, the position of the menu is displaced a few inches to the right of the mouse pointer.  The menu works, it just out of position.  Using Writer near the right edge of the screen helps a bit: the context menu is shown in full against the right edge.
Some Context

LibreOffice Calc behaves as it should (i.e. context menu is shown in the right position next to the mouse pointer). It's only recent version of Writer.
I have just started using KDE over Wayland instead of X.org. I am using Ubuntu Studio with the standard light look.
KDE Window Manager has permanently disabled the Shade function.

Is this a known Wayland problem, a known LibreOffice Writer problem or a KDE problem?

Version: 24.2.6.2 (X86_64) / LibreOffice Community
Build ID: 420(Build:2)
CPU threads: 12; OS: Linux 6.8; UI render: default; VCL: kf5 (cairo+wayland)
Locale: en-GB (en_GB.UTF-8); UI: en-GB
Ubuntu package version: 4:24.2.6-0ubuntu0.24.04.1
Calc: threaded
I'm not using the snap version of LibreOffice, but Ubuntu Studio is snap based.
